# Joda-Time DateTime.toDate() reverts back timezone

Tags: java, jodatime

I am trying to convert from one timezone to another using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

```
final DateTimeZone fromTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID("America/Los_Angeles");
final DateTimeZone toTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID(toTimeZoneString);
DateTime convertedStart = new DateTime(start, fromTimeZone).withZone(toTimeZone);

Date finalS = convertedStart.toDate();
```

I see that `finalS` loses the timezone and is reverted back to the original timezone when I do `.toDate()`. `convertedStart` is correctly converted.

start is in format  -> `Wed Jun 04 18:15:38 GMT 2014`.

---

Example:

```
start: Wed Jun 04 18:15:38 GMT 2014
toTimeZoneString is Asia/Kolkata
convertedStart : 2014-06-05T06:45:38.409+05:30
finalS: Wed Jun 04 18:15:38 GMT 2014
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Show us `toTimeZoneString` and `start` and `end`. Show us minimal but complete code.

Comment: Are you aware that the **java.util.Date class has no assigned time zone** yet it's implementation of the `toString` method confusingly applies the JVM’s default time zone? In contrast, a Joda-Time DateTime object does indeed have its own assigned time zone.

Comment: I don't understand toString comes into the picture here. The jodaTime.toDate() function calls new Date(getMillis())

Comment: But those unwieldy and difficult-to-parse string formats you show us come from java.util.Date's `toString` method. Joda-Time uses ISO 8601 formats when generating String representations of its values.

Comment: How do I fix this or should I use an alternate method for conversion?

Comment: Avoid java.util.Date & .Calendar whenever possible. Use only Joda-Time (or java.time). Do your debugging with Joda-Time's `toString` methods. If you want further help, show us minimal but complete code that compiles and runs. Writing that code for us may also bring you new understanding. Write that code for just one date-time, and forget about the distracting start-stop issue. You continue to ignore my first comment. And I suspect my second as well.

Comment: start and end comes to me from external sources which I cannot control. Also I need to send util.Date format back

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you refuse to post a complete working example of code, I'll make do with a little demo as an answer.

Example code using Joda-Time 2.3.

Use a java.util.Date only when forced, such as outputs/inputs to other classes.

```
java.util.Date dateIn = new java.util.Date(); // Avoid java.util.Date when possible.
```

Convert the Date to a Joda-Time DateTime, and assign a time zone. I am arbitrarily choosing [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Most or all of your business logic should be done in UTC unless business rules dictate use of a local time zone.

```
DateTime dateTimeUtc = new DateTime( dateIn, DateTimeZone.UTC ); // Convert Date to DateTime, assign UTC time zone.
```

Adjust the time zone from UTC to west coast of the United States. Use [proper time zone names](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (mostly continent/cityOrRegion) rather than 3 or 4 letter codes which are neither standardized nor unique.

```
DateTimeZone timeZoneLos_Angeles = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Los_Angeles" ); // Adjust time zone to United States.
DateTime dateTimeLos_Angeles = dateTimeUtc.withZone( timeZoneLos_Angeles );
```

Adjust to India time zone, five and a half hours ahead of UTC. Note that for [thread-safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) Joda-Time uses [immutable objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). Rather than make changes, we create a new instance while copying values from the original.

```
DateTimeZone timeZoneKolkata = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" ); // Adjust time zone to India.
DateTime dateTimeKolkata = dateTimeLos_Angeles.withZone( timeZoneKolkata );
```

Convert back to a j.u.Date if required.

```
java.util.Date dateOut = dateTimeKolkata.toDate();
```

Dump to console. Notice that, by default, Joda-Time creates String representations according to the [ISO 8601 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

```
System.out.println( "dateIn: " + dateIn ); // j.u.Date's "toString" method applies JVM's default time zone. Very confusing, as a j.u.Date has no time zone.
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );
System.out.println( "dateTimeLos_Angeles: " + dateTimeLos_Angeles );
System.out.println( "dateTimeKolkata: " + dateTimeKolkata );
System.out.println( "dateOut: " + dateOut ); // j.u.Date's "toString" method uses a terrible format. Use only in a pinch like debugging, never in production.
System.out.println( "Milliseconds since Unix epoch: " + dateIn.getTime() + " | " + dateTimeUtc.getMillis() + " | " + dateTimeLos_Angeles.getMillis() + " | " + dateTimeKolkata.getMillis() + " | " + dateOut.getTime()  );
```

When run…

```
dateIn: Wed Jun 04 13:51:01 PDT 2014
dateTimeUtc: 2014-06-04T20:51:01.593Z
dateTimeLos_Angeles: 2014-06-04T13:51:01.593-07:00
dateTimeKolkata: 2014-06-05T02:21:01.593+05:30
dateOut: Wed Jun 04 13:51:01 PDT 2014
Milliseconds since Unix epoch: 1401915061593 | 1401915061593 | 1401915061593 | 1401915061593 | 1401915061593
```

Understand that all of these date-time values represent **the same simultaneous moment**, the same point on the timeline of the Universe. Notice how the Strings vary across dates (June 4th and 5th), yet we are seeing the same moment. Imagine three people in Reykjavík, Los Angeles, and Kolkata all looking at their pocketwatch/phone at the same moment ([wall-clock time](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time)).