# Display next day date in other Country

Tags: java, android

I need to display next day of other country. For example: If in India on 20th April 2017 at 7PM, it will be 21st April 2017 in some other country then whenever i load the data before 7PM as per Indian datetime then it should display the at 7PM in India it will be 21st April 2017 in london.

Comment: **May be**, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093414/how-can-i-know-time-in-a-specific-country-if-i-am-in-a-differenet-country

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i know time in a specific country if i am in a differenet country?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093414/how-can-i-know-time-in-a-specific-country-if-i-am-in-a-differenet-country)